# android class using viewflipper

Tags: android

I am using four different class for the view now I want to combine the object of the four class in the one class then want to implement the ontouchlistener but it is showing me the error. I am not understanding that error. My code is as follow:

```
public class AdActivity extends Activity {

    DemoView demoview ;
    DemoView2 finalview;
    DemoView3 dview;
    DemoView4 deview;
    LowerView lview;
    Finalview fview;

    ViewFlipper c,d ;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        demoview = new DemoView(this);
        finalview = new DemoView2(this);
        dview= new DemoView3(this);
        deview = new DemoView4(this);
        lview= new LowerView(this);
        fview=new Finalview(this);
        setContentView(fview);
    }

    public class Finalview extends View {
        public Finalview(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            c=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper2);
            c.addView(demoview,0);
            c.addView(finalview, 1);
            c.addView(dview, 2);
            c.addView(deview, 3);
            c.setAutoStart(true);
            c.setFlipInterval(1000);
            c.startFlipping();

            d=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper3);
            d.addView(lview,0);
        }
    } 
}
```

my stack trace is showing the following error.i am not getting this error.

```
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ad/com.example.ad.AdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.example.ad.AdActivity$Finalview.<init>(AdActivity.java:420)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.example.ad.AdActivity.onCreate(AdActivity.java:44)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The important part of your stack trace is this:

```
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.example.ad.AdActivity$Finalview.<init>(AdActivity.java:420)
05-07 15:28:56.900: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.example.ad.AdActivity.onCreate(AdActivity.java:44)
```

It indicates that either 'c' or 'd' in the FinalView constructor is set to null by the call to findViewByID().

Are you sure that R.id.viewFlipper2 and R.id.viewFlipper3 are actually constructed themselves at the point that the AdActivity is created? Are these parts of the UI XML description for this activity?